# How to fetch DeviceScope using iot-service-client java

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I am trying to fetch the deviceScope of the deviceTwin. However, the deviceScope is not returned in the DeviceTwinDevice.

```
String iotHubConnectionString  = "xxx";

DeviceTwin twinClient = DeviceTwin.createFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionString);

SqlQuery sqlQuery = SqlQuery.createSqlQuery("*",SqlQuery.FromType.DEVICES,"capabilities.iotEdge=false",null);
Query twinQuery = twinClient.queryTwin(sqlQuery.getQuery());
            
DeviceTwinDevice d = twinClient.getNextDeviceTwin(twinQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/issues/1157`. Have to use registerManager

Comment: michael please verify this answer.